# Could the Infinity Stones destroyed by Thanos be recreated using the Infinity Stones collected from the past?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, infinity-stones

In the movie *Avengers: Endgame*, before the Avengers used the Quantum Realm machine to return each Infinity Stone back to its original timeline, could they have used Tony Stark's Infinity Gauntlet to recreate the Infinity Stones that were destroyed by Thanos? Perhaps Professor Hulk would be willing to wear the Infinity Gauntlet on his other arm and then snap the destroyed Infinity Stones back into their original form/shape.

These Infinity Stones should come back into their original form/shape because they technically still exist on an atomic level in the current timeline. We know this because Thanos had told the Avengers on the planet Titan II that he had reduced the Stones to atoms.

The only problem with doing this is that it may create a paradox of which there would be two sets of Infinity Stones existing in the same timeline, and this may have a disastrous result, such the Universe instantaneously exploding.

Yet, if doing so would not create any issues, then the Avengers would be able to keep one set of the Stones to have a fully working Infinity Gauntlet, and then they would return the other set of Stones to their original timelines and everything should be all good.

Could the Infinity Stones destroyed by Thanos be recreated using the Infinity Stones collected from the past?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could they? Presumably so but we don’t know for sure. The Infinity Stones were never “destroyed destroyed” as stated by Thanos and later confirmed out of universe too.

> **Thanos:** Gone. Reduced to atoms.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

We also know that the Infinity Stones work in the same universe but outside of their own timeline and they work on a similar scale to the timeline’s own Infinity Stones. We know this because of Smart Hulk’s and Tony’s snaps where at least the first is comparable to Thanos’.

Furthering that point the Snap to destroy the Stones is of a similar level to the Snap for killing half of all life in the universe.

> **Rocket:** When Thanos snapped his fingers, Earth become ground zero for a power surge of ridiculously cosmic proportions. No one’s seen anything like it.
>
> *He shifts the map, crossing billions of light years, to...AN IDENTICAL SURGE ENVELOPING A MYSTERIOUS, ORANGE PLANET.*
>
> **Rocket:** Until two days ago.
>
> **Natasha:** You’re saying he snapped his fingers again. Where?
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

If the Stones work on the same level to Thanos’ Snap and Thanos’ Snap is of comparable levels to his Snap to destroy them then the other timeline’s Stones should theoretically be able to reform them.

**However**, I don’t think they would want to. The universe is safer without the Infinity Stones in it and the Avengers exist to protect the universe. It would be in direct confrontation with their whole premise to bring them back. Sure they *could* try and bring them back and do some good things with them but with them back that opens the possibility for the Bad Guys to get their hands on them.

And even if they did actually try to get them they wouldn’t be able to. The most important thing is they wouldn’t get the Soul Stone: they need a sacrifice and the purpose for getting them just wouldn’t be great enough and of course *”We don’t trade lives.”*

And then even if they overcome that they have to get the Time Stone from The Ancient One and the Sorcerers Supreme. She only gave it to Smart Hulk initially because they convinced her Doctor Strange gave away the Stone for a reason. That reason is over with now, I doubt they’d be able to convince her afterwards.

---

Lastly, out of universe The Infinity Saga is over with now. The story has moved on. We might see the odd Stone show up from time to time but all six again? Probably not. It doesn’t make sense to remake the 23 movies all over again.

Comment: I agree with you that it would be a good idea not to have a working Infinity Gauntlet especially since a bad guy could get his/her hands on it. As far as the Ancient One is concerned, they would return the Time Stone to her via someone traveling to her timeline again through the Quantum Realm machine. It would be the same Time Stone that they had gotten from her in New York City back in her timeline.

Comment: @user255577 She only gave it up because of Strange. She didn’t want to give it up even for a second because of the splitting of time lines and the disaster out effects it could have in her own time line.

Comment: well, I guess what I'm trying to say is how would she know that the Avengers recreated the Stones that were destroyed by Thanos, or why would she even care if the Avengers were to do so? All she cares about is getting a Time Stone returned to her.

Comment: @user255577 she wouldn’t give the Stone away just because, and she didn’t in Endgame. There had to be a specific reason to give it away: in Endgame’s case because of Strange’s actions.

Comment: okay, I see what you are saying.